# In JQuery, what's the best way to get a data attribute of a set of nodes into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JQuery, what's the best way to get a data attribute of a set of nodes into an array?

I got this syntax working:

```
var ids = $("a.some_class").map(function(index, item) {return item.getAttribute('data-id');});
```

Is there any simpler syntax for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing easier than your [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) approach but, [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method with [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) will help to do the things in cross browser way and to return the pure JavaScript array:

```
var data = $('a.some_class').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get();
```

Comment: How is data different if you use or don't use .get()  ?  Thanks

Comment: @ZackXu `.get()` will convert the jQuery-wrapped object returned from `.map()` to the plain JavaScript array, so you'll be able to work with it as with a simple array.

Answer (score 1):

Try

[.data( key )](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
var ids = $("a.some_class").map(function() {
    return $(this).data('id'); //or return this.getAttribute('data-id');
}).get();
```